# Devops Pull Request workflow validations

Tags: azure-devops

We are using Azure devops with the workflow for each task as:

1. Task branch to Release branch
2. Then Release branch to master

The reviewer will approve each pull request.
However, a user creating a PR can also create one from task branch directly to master.

[image]

Is there any way, by policies/validations that the system can prevent creation of the PR itself, which is from task to master.

Comment: We would very much like to have the ability to limit branches that can be pulled directly into a given branch. This would complete the policy chain of trust, such that we set project-level policy on, say, branch names that start with "pbi/" and then have requirement that only branches that start with "pbi/" can be pulled into the main branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently azure devops doesnot have the policies/validations to prevent creating a pr which is task to master.

However, there is workaround to prevent merging the PR which is task to master.

You can create a pipeline with a script task to check the source branch of the PR. See below:

```
$sourceBranch = "$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"

if($sourceBranch -ne "refs/heads/release")
{
    exit 1
}
```

For example add a powershell task with above script. The script will check if the PR source branch is release branch, and fail the pipeline if it is not.

Then you can add above pipeline to the [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) of master branch. See below:

[image]

Then any PR which is not release to master will fail to be validated and cannot be completed. (But it still cannot prevent creating a PR from test to master)

You can also click [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to submit a feature request(Click Suggest a feature and select Azure Devops. ) to Microsoft development team. Hopefully they will consider adding this feature in the future.

**See below screenshot from my test pipeline.**
[image]

Comment: Create a YAML Pipeline for this workaround to work. 
From Microsoft docs,  $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)  "This variable is only available in a YAML pipeline if the PR is affected by a branch policy."

Comment: I tested on classic pipeline. It worked. Donot know why it said so in document. See above my test result.

Comment: It is worth noting that if someone has permissions on the branch to "Bypass policies when completing pull requests", this control will not catch that case.  It is better to just restrict access through repo security to people you trust to manage the merge to master.

Comment: Yes. It's working in Classic pipeline also. I think Microsoft docs needs an updation there.

Comment: In testing, it appears that this only works if the workaround pipeline that is run in the build validation is in the same repo as the branch that has the build validation policy. If it's in a different repo, it fails with the following error and no logs: "An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I got this working for both classic and YAML pipelines, but with the YAML pipeline, you can specify `checkout:none` in the steps which makes this way faster with larger repositories because the code isn't pulled from source control first before the script (which doesn't use any of the source code) is evaluated. I couldn't find a way to stop it pulling the latest source using a classic pipeline, so it was always a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a subset of users to manage the merge to master, you can setup branch security on the master branch that prevents contributing to pull requests that would target that branch.

[image]

Comment: I want the system to prompt/prevent when creating a PR which is task to master. Is tthat possible.

Comment: I don't think there is anything that prevents the PR from being created against the branch.  But if you define security the "Complete" button will never be available except for who you grant access to.